# App limit on a single Heroku account

Tags: heroku

Is there a limit to the number of apps I can host with a single Heroku account?

I currently run multiple apps each using 1 dyno for free. But could I host hundreds (or even thousands) of small applications for free?

I also know there is a 2TB bandwidth soft limit, but is there any other limitation I could encounter?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A clear answer surfaced in the Heroku July 2013 newsletter about platform limits. The maximum number of apps per account is 100.

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#maximum-number-of-apps

Comment: Moreover, unverified accounts can have up to 5 apps. (a verified account is an account with credit card information attached to it)

Answer (score 17):

There's currently no limit on the number of apps that you can create, but please see item 4.4 of the [Heroku Terms of Service](https://policy.heroku.com/tos).

```
You may not develop multiple Applications to simulate or act as a single
Application or otherwise access the Heroku Services in a manner intended
to avoid incurring fees.
```

Answer (score 13):

If you have unverified account then the maximum number of apps is 5 only and for verified account number is 100.

Answer (score 3):

Unverified accounts can create at most 5 apps. Verified accounts can create no more than 200 apps.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#maximum-number-of-applications

PS: To verify your account you'll need to provide a payment method (credit/debit/prepaid card).

Comment: If I have an unverified account and more than 5 apps, is Heroku gonna charge me?

Comment: @user1941537 They won't allow you to create more than 5 apps, they will ask to add a payment method. But they won't charge anything until you upgraded your plan.

Answer (score 0):

Verified accounts can create up to 100 apps whereas unverified accounts can create up to 5 apps only. To get verified you have to add your credit card details in the account setting section.
Alternatively, you can also use a team account.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits